# Can the main browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Edge) show you if a PDF is protected or not?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, pdf-reader

Windows' built-in PDF reader is basically Edge and other main browsers have built-in PDF readers too.

Can any of them somehow show you if the PDF you read is protected against editing or not?

Is there a symbol inside the reader that tells you that?

**Example:** The PDF that is linked from https://www.reddit.com/r/LawSchool/comments/6t29ym/nyle_question_control_f_not_working_on_outline/

Comment: Do you have an example PDF that's edit-protected?

Comment: It was practically impossible to find an online example. It seems most file owners who protect their files don't want to expose they did so. But I found an example nonetheless and added it to the question. Does it help?

Comment: Try to use this extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm. It should give you the option to show the properties. Maybe there are similar extensions for other browsers. I can't find any native function for that either in the default PDF-viewers. They are probably too basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick rundown of what you see with Firefox, Chromium, Edge and Foxit Reader. I tested the referenced New York Course Materials PDF, along with other non-protected PDFs. Just to be doubly sure, I've tried opening these PDFs as a file as well as a URL to make sure there's no unusual behaviour with local files.

**Foxit Reader** isn't a browser, but we'll use it as a control in this test to show that it recognizes a document is protected. This is shown in the title bar and the file properties panel.

[image: Foxit Reader]

**Microsoft Edge** doesn't directly indicate anything, but upon closer inspection, the Add Notes button is only ever disabled on the protected documents.

[image: Microsoft Edge]

**Chromium** doesn't give any indication at all. There's nothing available on the toolbar related to modifying the document or inspecting its metadata.

[image: Chromium]

**Firefox** is the same as Chromium.

[image: Firefox]

So, go figure... Edge is your best bet!

Comment: Great discovery about Edge! Just one problem: as you can see in your Foxit screenshot, "Adding Notes" is only a specific type of protection. A file can be protected without it.

Comment: I guess it depends on the semantics of whether 'adding a note' is considered as 'commenting' or 'changing the document' as far as PDF security goes.

Comment: I don't think it matters. As long as even one restriction (from the list in your screenshot) is "Not Allowed", then the file should be considered as protected.

Comment: Well, I think that given what I've shown so far, you're not going to find a browser that gives any more info than Edge, and Edge only goes so far, sadly!

Comment: Alright, I've therefore accepted your answer.